# Vector Space for Cartesian Product

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

I am stuck on this problem and could use some guidance. It has been a number of years since I took undergrad linear algebra, as well as, a disconnect of fogginess happening. Anyway,

Suppose V and W are vector spaces. Show that V × W satisfies all the
axioms of a vector space.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Is this a cross product or a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)?

Comment: Cross products are not part of a vector space's definition. You don't have to confirm them.

Comment: "Cross product" has a usual meaning, and this is not it. This type of product is usually called a "cartesian product" or a "direct product". Also, "I can reference the existence of V and W as vector spaces in each axiom of the cross product" is a bit of a word salad...

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the first axiom, that vector addition is commutative. I'll leave it to you to work out the remaining seven.

We want to show that if $\mathbf{x}\in V\times W$ and $\mathbf{y}\in V\times W$ are vectors, then $\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{y}+\mathbf{x}$. Recall that addition in $V\times W$ is defined as follows: if $(a,b),(c,d)\in V\times W$ (so that $a,c\in V$ and $b,d\in W$), then
$$(a,b) + (c,d) = \bigl( a+_V c, b+_W d\bigr),$$
where $+_V$ is the addition of $V$, and $+_W$ is the addition of $W$. So write $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2)$, $\mathbf{y}=(y_1,y_2)$, with $x_1,y_1\in V$, $x_2,y_2\in W$. We have:
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y} &= (x_1,x_2) + (y_1,y_2) = \bigl( x_1+_V y_1, x_2+_Wy_2\bigr);\\
\mathbf{y}+\mathbf{x} &= (y_1,y_2) + (x_1,x_2) = \bigl (y_1+_V x_1, y_2+_W x_2\bigr).
\end{align*}$$
Now, since $V$ is already  known to be a vector space, we know that $+_V$ is commutative; that is, $x_1+_Vy_1 = y_1+_V x_1$. So at least the first components of $\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}$ and $\mathbf{y}+\mathbf{x}$ agree.

I'll leave it to you to do the rest.

(You also need to clean up a bit your wording and terminology, as noted in the comments)